# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

An error has occurred on WLS 12.2.1.3:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1113)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
```

org.springframework.* is exists in weblogic.xml and weblogic-application.xml in prefer-application-packages block.

dependency hierarchy is ok in pom.xml

[image]

spring libs is ok in war too.

[image]

Any idea what i can check additionally?

Comment: Probably you can try attaching with jvisualvm (or similar) and checking the run-time classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of jar conflicts.

1. There may be classpath being set outside of the war which you can see from the weblogic startup command classpath variable and make sure no other versions of spring in included in the classpath
2. please run `mvn dependency:tree` and make sure you're not pulling in any another version of spring dependency (which i think you did)

Comment: mvn dependency:tree do not show any other versions of springframework. only 3.0.5.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

dependencyManagement was added into war pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```